# Using Telerik Kendo in ASP.NET Core MVC Web application

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core, telerik

I am starting with usage of Telerik Kendo UI in my ASP.NET core sample web application. I am following the guide descried here: http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started
I have paid account for Telerik and the same I am using to install NugetPackge in my solution from private Nuget feed of Telerik.

We are doing a collaborative development using Bitbucket and when others download my solution they get error while Restoration of Packages in .Net Core MVC web app.

Error: Unable to resolve 'Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core (>= 2017.1.118)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.

Do I need to configure the Telerik private feed in every developer's Visual Studio? Can anyone please point me in the right direction how can we use Telerik Kendo for our Product in Production environment. I am new to this, kindly pardon my meager understanding(s).

Thanks.

Comment: IANAL, but I believe every developer will need their own paid license of Telerik to be in compliance with licenses if you distribute the Telerik Kendo UI this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to either:

1) setup the private nuget feed on each other developers environment so they can restore the Telerik Kendo UI package

or

2) configure the private feed in the nuget.config file in the .nuget folder of the solution

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Contoso Package Source" value="https://contoso.com/packages/" />
    <add key="Test source" value="c:\packages" />
</packageSources>
```

Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file

Comment: If you want to go with option 2 that @chambo suggested and you are working with VS2017 then all you have to do is add a NuGet.Config file next to your .sln file, add a package source to point to a relative folder path (ex. packages), and then add that folder next to the .sln file and include the necessary NuGet packages in that folder. That way each developer will be able to restore the Telerik package without having to setup the Telerik NuGet feed on their local environment.